# ListAdapter Filter other than using Strings?

Tags: android, listview, filter, listadapter

It seems that the use case for an [`Adapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) that is [`Filterable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html) is to filter by a `String` or `CharSequence` that might be entered by the user in an [`EditText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html), but is this really the only criteria the platform offers for filtering [`Adapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html)s?

What if I have a backing data structure of objects that can be otherwise categorized? for example, what if I have a list of Shirt objects that have an `enum` attribute, `color`? The user should be able to filter the list of shirts from a list of available `color`s. As a good application developer I want to use the platforms built in filtering mechanism, but all I can find is this [`Filter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html) with methods like [`filter (CharSequence constraint)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html#filter%28java.lang.CharSequence%29). I must be missing something. I see how it would be simple enough to implement this filtering mechanism inside my own custom [`BaseAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html), but it feels like there should be some built in way to do custom filters. Anyone? Thanks in advance.

Comment: FacebookSDK 3.0 do have a way of filtering on other parameters. The trouble is that they have implemented the new filter class from ground up.

Check PickerFragment.GraphObjectFilter<T> for more details.

Comment: I can't believe this question doesn't have more views and up votes. The reality behind the OP's question underscores a completely idiotic exclusion from the core android framework. Filtering on anything other than String's? Who the hell needs that? Unbelievable

Answer (score 0):

In Android, your adapter can **implement** the Filterable (that may be same with Filter you searched)
=> This is the connection between your data with the Filter.
Here is the link 
[*You should see the marked answer*] [List View Filter Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663725/list-view-filter-android)

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own FilterAdapter and bring your own logics, for example this one take care of object with two strings and manage the filter:

```
public class TwoWordsFilter extends Filter {
ArrayList<BranchData> branchDatas = new ArrayList<BranchData>();
private BranchDataAdapter branchDataAdapter;
public TwoWordsFilter(ArrayList<BranchData> branchDatas,BranchDataAdapter branchDataAdapter) {
    this.branchDatas = branchDatas;
    this.branchDataAdapter=branchDataAdapter;
}

@Override
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
    if (constraint==null || constraint.length()==0){
        results.values=branchDatas;
        results.count=branchDatas.size();
    }else {
        List<BranchData> mBranchDatas=new ArrayList<BranchData>();
        for (BranchData branchData : branchDatas) {
            if (branchData.getBranch_name().trim().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().trim().toLowerCase()) ||
            branchData.getCity().trim().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().trim().toLowerCase())){
                mBranchDatas.add(branchData);
            }
        }
        results.values=mBranchDatas;
        results.count=mBranchDatas.size();

    }
    return results;
}

@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
    if (results.count == 0)
        branchDataAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    else {
        branchDataAdapter.setBranchDatas((ArrayList<BranchData>) results.values);
        branchDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}

in your adapter put this:

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (twoWordsFilter==null){
        twoWordsFilter=new TwoWordsFilter(branchDatas,this);
    }
    return twoWordsFilter;
}
```